# How do I limit rows with HBase API REST scanner?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

What I'm trying to do is translate this hbase shell scan

```
scan 'mytable', { LIMIT => 100, FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter('cf', 'col', =, 'binary:value')" }
```

into a HBase API REST call

```
PUT /mytable/scanner

<Scanner>
  <filter>
    {
      "type: "SingleColumnValueFilter",
      "op": "EQUAL",
      "family": "Y2Y=",
      "qualifier": "Y29s",
      "latestVersion": true,
      "comparator": {
         "type": "BinaryComparator",
         "value": "c2VhcmNo"
      }
    }
  </filter>
</Scanner
```

The filter is working correctly but I can't find a way to limit my results.

In this [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html#xmlschema), there is no **limit** attribute for the **Scanner** element. There is the **batch** attribute but it limits the number of values returned instead of the number of rows returned.

For example,

```
Person1
  cf:name=John
  cf:age=30
Person2
  cf:name=Sarah
  cf:age=20
```

then

```
<Scanner batch="3">...</Scanner>
```

will return

```
Person1
  cf:name=John
  cf:age=30
Person2
  cf:name=Sarah
```

Is it even possible to limit with the REST API and filters included ?

Answer (score 0):

public Scan readVersions(int versions)
Get up to the specified number of versions of each column.
Parameters:
versions - specified number of versions for each column
Returns:
this